# How to make `ng-if` `false` only on function called, with others are set true

Tags: angularjs

I have a scenario here, when the parent clicked by user, the children need to show the description. as well if the user click on the other parent the child need to show the description.

i use the `ng-if` - the proplem is, when the parent is marked as true the child show the descrition. but when another parent set to true the current parent sets the `ng-if` as false.

how to set `true` by parent and set `false` by only on child click?

In case if there is  a correct way to approach let me know.

here is my code :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

var array = [{'name':'one'}, {'name':'two'}, {'name':'three'}];


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.names = array;

    $scope.setCurrent = function(n) {

        $scope.current = n;

    }

});
```

html :

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="n in names" ng-click="setCurrent(n.name)"> {{n.name}}
    <h2 ng-if="current==n.name">{{n.name | uppercase }} >
    <span>on click only need to Close</span>
    </h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/htzpM2Rn6Z7drc9OdR29?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property `show` in your array list

Then make that property `true`/`false` to maintain `hide`/`show`

Try like this

```
 <li ng-repeat="n in names" ng-click="n.show=!n.show">
    {{n.name}}
    <h2 ng-if="n.show">{{n.name | uppercase }} <span>Close</span></h2>
</li>
```

<kbd>**[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/mclbD2NNfsiVU6Enaysu?p=preview)**</kbd>